# Can't add values to ManyToMany after creating an entity of the JoinTable (1-n-1)

Tags: symfony

At first I had a ManyToMany relation between the User and Club entity. 
Now, I wanted to add a column in the JoinTable (users_clubs) so I had to create a third entity UserClub. I ran the doctrine:schema:update --force command and all seemed to be fine.

I have my ProfileForm setup with an Entity field like this:

```
->add(
  'clubs', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeMainBundle:Club',
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => 'true',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) 
    {
      return $er->createQueryBuilder('club')
        ->orderBy('club.name', 'ASC');
    },
  )
)
```

The form renders well but I get this error when saving the form:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User::addClub() must be  an instance of Acme\MainBundle\Entity\UserClub, instance of Acme\MainBundle\Entity\Club given in /src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php
```

User entity addClub function:

```
/**
 * Add clubs
 *
 * @param UserClub $userClub
 * @return User
 */
public function addClub(UserClub $userClub)
{
    if (!$this->userClubs->contains($userClub)) 
    {
        $this->userClubs->add($userClub);
        $userClub->setUser($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by following this guide:

http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/07/symfnoy2-many-to-many-relation-with.html

I changed my addClub function and added a setClubs function which takes care of setting the club and user in the new UserClub entity.

Answer (score 0):

```
->add(
  'clubs', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeMainBundle:Club',
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => 'true',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) 
    {
      return $er->createQueryBuilder('club')
        ->orderBy('club.name', 'ASC');
    },
  )
)
```

Can you post your user Entity please ?
Does your user club are nammed user_clubs in your User entity ?

If yes :

```
->add(
  'userclubs', 'entity', array(....
```

not :

```
->add(
  'clubs', 'entity', array(
```